# How to substract hashmap data in java

Tags: java, android, hashmap, equation

I save my data in hashmap. I have two hashmap data, one from database and one from activity result. I want to do some equation with that data, but only if key in activity math with database key. I try to substract activity data with the database data, but the result is always 0.

Data from database and result activity is passed to this hashmap class:

```
public class PositionData implements Serializable {
private String name;
    public HashMap<String, Integer> values;
    public HashMap<String,String> routers;
    public PositionData(String name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.name=name;
        values = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        routers = new HashMap<String, String>();

    }
    public void addValue(Router router,int strength){

        values.put(router.getBSSID(), strength);
        routers.put(router.getBSSID(),router.getSSID());

    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String toString() {
        String result="";
        result+=name+"\n";
        for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> e: this.values.entrySet())
                 result+=routers.get(e.getKey())+" : "+e.getValue().toString()+"\n";

        return result;  

    }
    public HashMap<String, Integer> getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> getRouters() {
        return routers;
    }
```

And this is how i do substraction in activity class:

```
PositionData positionData = (PositionData) intent
                .getSerializableExtra("PositionData");

positionsData=db.getReadings(building);

HashMap<String, Integer> rssi = positionData.getValues();
HashMap<String, Integer> rssi1 = positionsData.get(0).getValues();
HashMap<String, String> dest = positionsData.get(0).getRouters();

int dista =  0;
if (positionData.equals(dest)){
dista = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(rssi))-Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(rssi1));
        }

        Log.v("dis:", String.valueOf(dista));
```

I have data from class database and class result, both data is passed to HashMap activity to get `positionData` form. After i get the form, i calculate it in equation class. So, here i have 4 class.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are trying to compare the contents of a `HashMap` to object `PositionData`. You may have to override `PositionData`'s `.equals()` method so it knows how to compare its contents to a `HashMap`. Maybe something like the following:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
  if (this == o) {
    return true;
  }
  if (o instanceof Map) {
     Map m = (HashMap) o;
    /* loop through both data structures and compare, return true if same */
  }
  /* compare two instances of PositionData */

  return false;
```

Another option is to write a method to iterate through both and compare their contents, without the need of using/overriding `.equals()`.

Comment: ```positionData``` is that ```HashMap``` activity name. you can see in ```HashMap``` activity like
```public PositionData(String name) {```

Comment: Ahhh, yes, sorry for not realizing that. I believe your problem is that you are trying to use .equals() to compare objects of 2 different types, which will always return false unless there is an override. Which values are you trying to compare extactly?

Comment: Also, you are not extracting a value from ```rssi``` or ```rssi1```. You are trying to convert a HashMap to a String and then to an Integer. You should use ```rssi.get(KEY)``` which will return you the integer value in the rssi hashmap that is mapped to ```KEY```.

Comment: Both data from activity database and activity scanning is passed to that ```positionData``` activity. So data from database and activity has the ```positionData``` form. 
As you can see, HashMap values contain ```Strength``` and ```BSSID```. what i want to compare is if the BSSID from scanning is equal with the BSSID in database, and i want to substract or do equation to strength value.

Comment: Okay, I see. But can you clarify you what your intent is with this line ```if (positionData.equals(dest)) {```? Because you cannot compare an object of ```PositionData``` to an object of ```HashMap``` the system does not know how to handle that because the types are different.

Comment: I don't know, i want to use if  ```positionData.contain()``` instead of equals() actually. but it give an error so i just use equal.

Answer (score 0):

I create generic example for you. I think that can help you understand how you can do equation on your hashmaps.

```java
HashMap<String, Integer> activity= new HashMap<String, Integer>();
HashMap<String, Integer> database = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
Iterator iter = activity.keySet().iterator(); // getting iterator from keySet from one of hashmaps

// Iterate through one of hashmaps keys
    while(iter.hasNext()){
      String s = (String) iter.next();
      if(database.containsKey(s)){ // finding key in second hashmap
        // in here you can do your equation;
      }
    }
```

Comment: i don't understand with that activity and database HashMap, i get activity and database from different class